How to get column-wise summary statistics with missing codes?
I have written a custom function ord_table() to extract summary statistics from a series of databases. To get those summary statistics, I have to filter out missing data codes (all codes are large negative numbers).
> data
     var1 var2   var3   var4
1       3    2      2      1
2  -99999    3      1      1
3       3    5 -99999      2
4       2    3      3      3
5       2    3      4      4
6  -99999    1 -99999      5
7       3    4      1      5
8       5    1      3      3
9       4    1      5 -99999
10 -99999    5      4      1
11 -99999    3      2      2
12      1    2      5      5

The column names are in a vector ord_vars.
I am applying the function with lapply.
ordinal <- lapply(ord_vars, ord_table)

Here is my function:
ord_table <- function(x) {
  table_ord <- data.frame(Median=double(length=1), 
                          Minimum=double(length=1), 
                          Maximum=double(length=1), 
                          IQR=double(length=1))
  table_ord$Median <- data %>% subset(x > 0) %>% pull(x) %>% median()
  table_ord$Minimum <- data %>% subset(x > 0) %>% pull(x) %>% min()
  table_ord$Maximum <- data %>% subset(x > 0) %>% pull(x) %>% max()
  table_ord$IQR <- data %>% subset(x > 0) %>% pull(x) %>% IQR() 
  return(table_ord)
}

It is all working except for the subsetting to remove the negative values that code for missing data.
I have tried filter() and subset(), and both with unquote(x) instead of x.
For each dataframe, I get results including missing data codes:
[[1]]
  Median Minimum Maximum      IQR
1      2  -99999       5 100002.2

Where I want to get:
[[1]]
  Median Minimum Maximum  IQR
1    2.5       2       5 2.25

data
set.seed(123)  ## for sake of reproducibility
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -99999)
var1 <- sample(a, 12, replace=TRUE)
var2 <- sample(a, 12, replace=TRUE)
var3 <- sample(a, 12, replace=TRUE)
var4 <- sample(a, 12, replace=TRUE)
data <- cbind(var1, var2, var3, var4) %>% as.data.frame()

ord_vars <- data %>% colnames() %>% as.vector() 


If you use filter, you can create a symbol from you string, then defuse with {{, so:
ord_table <- function (x) {
  table_ord <- data.frame(Median = double(length = 1),
                          Minimum = double(length = 1),
                          Maximum = double(length = 1),
                          IQR = double(length = 1)
  )
  x <- sym(x)
  table_ord$Median <- data %>% filter({{x}} > 0) %>% pull(x) %>% median()
  table_ord$Minimum <- data %>% filter({{x}} > 0) %>% pull(x) %>% min()
  table_ord$Maximum <- data %>% filter({{x}} > 0) %>% pull(x) %>% max()
  table_ord$IQR <- data %>% filter({{x}} > 0) %>% pull(x) %>% IQR() 
  return(table_ord) 
}

But I would probably do something like this, and actually set the values as NA (ideally you would do this when you read in the data):
library(tidyverse)
data |> 
  mutate(across(test_vars, \(v) na_if(v, -99999))) |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = test_vars) |> 
  drop_na() |> 
  summarise(
    mean = mean(value), min = min(value), max = max(value), IQR = IQR(value),
    .by = name
  )


# A tibble: 4 × 5
  name   mean   min   max   IQR
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 var3   3.2      1     5   2  
2 var4   2.58     1     5   1.5
3 var2   2.44     1     5   2  
4 var1   3.33     1     5   1



Worked perfectly. Thank you!

I've seen highly cited papers that still included such missing codes in their statistics. You definitely should set them to NA before analysis to avoid this mistake.
Actually it's quite easy by equating your dataset with the missing codes. If these were e.g. -77777, -88888, -99999, you would proceed as follows:
> dat
      V1     V2     V3     V4
1      4 -77777      5      3
2      3 -99999      3      5
3 -88888      5      2      5
4      1      2 -88888      5
5      5 -99999      2 -99999
6      3      3      2      1
> dat[dat == -77777 | dat == -88888 | dat == -99999] <- NA
> dat
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  4 NA  5  3
2  3 NA  3  5
3 NA  5  2  5
4  1  2 NA  5
5  5 NA  2 NA
6  3  3  2  1

To get summary statistics of the median, minimum, maximum, and IQR of specific columns, you can write a small stat_fun() that combines their calculation.
You already know you can use lapply (like list-apply) to loop over columns. If you're expecting just numbers as a result you can use sapply (like simplified-apply) which simplifies the result in a numeric matrix. Maybe you know, that you can also use functions as a function argument. So we can write stat_fun() in a way it sapplyes a named vector of the functions median, min, max, IQR over a numeric vector (a column), and then we sapply this function over specific columns to get the statistics; importantly we include the na.rm=TRUE argument since we now have NAs in the data:
> stat_fun <- \(x) sapply(c(median=median, min=min, max=max, IQR=IQR), \(f) {
+   f(x, na.rm=TRUE)
+ })
> 
> ord_vars <- c('V1', 'V2', 'V4')
> sapply(dat[ord_vars], stat_fun)
       V1  V2 V4
median  3 3.0  5
min     1 2.0  1
max     5 5.0  5
IQR     1 1.5  2

Note, that missing values are usually imputed during data analysis; you should look into data imputation.

Data:
> dput(dat)
structure(list(V1 = c(4, 3, -88888, 1, 5, 3), V2 = c(-77777, 
-99999, 5, 2, -99999, 3), V3 = c(5, 3, 2, -88888, 2, 2), V4 = c(3, 
5, 5, 5, -99999, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

